# Does sparse matrix work with MultinomialNB?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, naivebayes

I have a BoW vectors of shape (`100000, 56000`) and I want to use `MultinomialNB` from scikit-learn for a classification task.

Does `MultinomialNB` take sparse matrix for fitting the data?

I can't seem to convert it into dense matrix`toarray()` due to memory error. If NB classifier doesn't take sparse matrix are there any alternatives I could use for fitting the data without converting it into dense matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.fit) of `MultinomialNB.fit` (emphasis added):

> `fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)`
>
> Parameters:
>
> X : {array-like, **sparse matrix**}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>
> Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.